# Getting error message The Operation could not be completed in Visual Studio -Winform

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, compiler-errors, windows-runtime

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and I am getting the error below message while I run my Windows from application first time.

> The Operation could not be completed

But when I run next time the project runs without any message. Can you guide me why this happens? and how to fix this. Earlier this did not happen.[image]

Comment: Only on the first time? Not the second or third? Have you tried reinstalling Visual Studio?

Comment: Every first time after saving my work,  when I run it. I got this error in Pop up box. But when I click Ok and again run, it runs completely without pop up

Comment: Find the ".suo" file of your solution and delete it.

Comment: yes, it worked for me. Thanks!!

Comment: For me it as coming on aspx and it worked after deleting .suo file of the solution.